# How to terminate a batch file

Tags: cmd

While this question has been asked before, I have not found the solution to my particular problem. I am trying to launch the windows calculator from a bat file. It launches the program but the console window remains open. Typing exit or exit /b, does not help. This is what the file looks like:

```
C:\Windows\System32\calc.exe 
exit
```

I tried typing exit before the launch command. It works and the program is not launched. It is as though the very act of launching the program renders all succeeding instructions null and void.

Comment: The exit instruction is on the following line.

Comment: Please read the output of the `EXIT /?` command.

Comment: When I run this code, calc opens and the batch window disappears. Invoking the calc app would be better expressed as `"%__appdir__%calc.exe"`

Comment: I also can't replicate your issue (at least not with `calc.exe`; other programs may act differently)

Comment: I assume you're looking to use the `start` command, and for information regarding its usage, use `start /?` in a Command Prompt window. The following single line should suffice, `Start "" "%SystemRoot%\System32\calc.exe"`. If you want to close the Command  Prompt, on success, append `&& Exit`, i.e. `Start "" "%SystemRoot%\System32\calc.exe" && Exit`